# Ractive 'Consider initialising your data to eliminate the ambiguity' issue

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I have a object that's passed to my Ractive component via binding like this:

```
<Component obj={{someObject}} />
```

and in `Component` i've got the following oninit method defined:

```
oninit: function () {
  this.set('someObjectClone', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.get('someObject'))));
}
```

However using `someObjectClone` for two-way binding a `<input>` element in my template results in a warning saying:

> Ractive.js:  The 'someObjectClone.someValue' reference being used for two-way binding is ambiguous, and may cause unexpected results. Consider initialising your data to eliminate the ambiguity

and if i just try to print the value without using two-way binding it prints nothing. As if the value isn't set at all. But if i do `console.log(this.get())` in my `oninit` i can see that it has been set. Is the DOM not updating?

Could anybody fill me in on this?

I'm using Ractive `0.8.0-edge` and i set up a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kjj6s709/3/)

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example `event` is set to `some` in the component parameters:

```
<Component event="{{some}}"/>
```

And you copy that object to the `clone` path:

```
this.set('clone',  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.get('event'))) );
```

So in your template, use `{{clone.value}}`.

As to the ambiguous ref warning, set a default value in your data so that Ractive knows the value is to be found at the root of the component (see http://jsfiddle.net/kjj6s709/6/):

```
data: {
    clone: null
},
```

Comment: Ah, of course! I'm stupid, what a mistake! Thanks a lot, you just keep saving my day @martypdx